# How to Batch Upload .docx Files as Posts

Tags: plugins, posts

I need to upload all the articles from our school newspaper to our website at once. They all need to publish at a specified date at a specified time and all of them have authors (users) and an image associated with them. Doing it one by one takes ages, especially because the server is very slow (and therefor going from page to page takes a while). Is there any way to do them all at once? Or any tips on how to get them done faster?

Comment: Ehm... upload articles... what sort of "articles"? XML content? If yes, what's the source? etc. etc. Needs waaay more info.

Comment: @kaiser Oops, sorry. I was in the wrong "mode" when I wrote this so to speak. The "articles" are .docx files in a folder.

Comment: @kaiser "articles" = posts